# Laravel update one field of a model relation

Tags: laravel, eloquent, laravel-8

I am trying to update only one field on a models relation but it keeps returning it as null and I cant figure out why;

The `profile` is a `belongsTo` relationship

```php
$user = User::find(1);

$user->profile->api_key = 'apikeyhere';
$user->save();
```

After i do this and then run `dd($user->profile)` .. The api_key field is null instead of the actual value.

Comment: please share your model details

Comment: why you are writing like this $user->profile->api_key = 'apikeyhere';?

Comment: Im just trying to update a field

Comment: try $user->profile= 'apikeyhere';

Comment: @eraufi .. There is no profile field on the user model ... As mentioned, the profile is a relationship to another table

Comment: could please share some more code like from your user table and from you relation table

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using two query

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->profile()->update([ 'api_key' => 'apikeyhere']);
```

Using One query

```
Profile::where('user_id', 1)->update([ 'api_key' => 'apikeyhere']);
```

Answer (score 0):

Update the field using the relation.

```
$user = User::find(1);
$user->profile()->update(['api_key' => 'api_key value']);
```